# Windows 10 CredentialProvider Tile Image transparency

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windows-10, credential-providers

A while ago, I have created a CredentialProvider for Windows 7 that showed a custom tile image for the user. When I tested my CredentialProvider on Windows 10, I noticed that the tile image is not round as the usual Windows user image is, so I assumed, I have to provide my own round image with transparency. I tried to load a transparent PNG with the round shape and pass the corresponding `HBITMAP` in the `ICredentialProviderCredentiall::GetBitmapValue()` function. Unfortunately, instead of being transparent, the background of the PNG is white. Is there any way to show the actual transparency? Since the `HBITMAP` is drawn by LogonUI itself, I cannot modify the drawing behavior.

To create the `HBITMAP` out of my PNG resource, I use the following function:

```
HBITMAP LoadPNG(HINSTANCE hInst, int resourceId)
{
    HGLOBAL     hGlobal;
    LPSTREAM    pStream;
    HBITMAP tBmp = NULL;
    ULONG_PTR token = 0;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartupInput input = NULL;
    Gdiplus::GdiplusStartup(&token, &input, NULL);
    if (token != 0)
    {
        HRSRC   hRsrc = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(resourceId), TEXT("PNG"));
        HGLOBAL hGlob1 = LoadResource(hInst, hRsrc);

        int size = SizeofResource(hInst, hRsrc);

        hGlobal = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED, size);
        LPVOID  resPtr = LockResource(hGlob1);
        memcpy(hGlobal, resPtr, size);
        FreeResource(hGlob1);
        CreateStreamOnHGlobal(hGlobal, true, &pStream);
        Gdiplus::Bitmap* bmp = new Gdiplus::Bitmap(pStream, false);

        bmp->GetHBITMAP(Gdiplus::Color::Transparent, &tBmp);

        Gdiplus::GdiplusShutdown(token);
    }
    return tBmp;
}
```

I tried also other values for the  `GetHBITMAP()` background color parameter such as `AlphaMask` and `AlphaShift`, but these did not work either (instead, the white background turned black)

Is there any way to accomplish my goal?

Comment: Are you sure that the `Bitmap` object does contain an alpha channel? The c'tor taking an `IStream*` may not be able to decide between ARGB and PARGB, and simply discards the alpha channel altogether. Have you verified the existence of an alpha channel by calling [Image::GetFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535376.aspx) and checking for the `ImageFlagsHasAlpha` and `ImageFlagsHasTranslucent` [ImageFlags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534136.aspx)?

Comment: Apparently it has the `ImageFlagsHasAlpha`, but not `ImageFlagsHasTranslucent` flags..

Comment: Looking at the code again it appears that you are returning a GDI `HBITMAP`. Even though the documentation for [Bitmap::GetHBITMAP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536295.aspx) leaves much to be desired, it appears as though it constructs a fully opaque image that is constructed from the source image, the alpha channel, and the background color provided as a parameter. GDI bitmaps - with very few exceptions (e.g. [AlphaBlend](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183351.aspx)) - do not use or support the alpha channel.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The newest [Credential Provider Technical Reference](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=717287) (which is not that easy to find on MSDN) actually tells what the issue with the tile image is:

> In Windows 10, the selected User/V1/PLAP credential provider has an
>   image size of 192x192. The ones on the bottom left list is of 48x48.
>   **Note LogonUI uses circular image for user and *square* image for V1/PLAP
>   according to the new design direction.** The image size of V2 Credential
>   Provider tile under a selected user is 48x48.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation correctly then the challenge must be somehow to convince the LogonUI that its a User and not a V1/PLAP, I think this could be archieved returning a dummy user in the GetSerialization call.